# Need help on Hexadecimal course

Tags: memory, hex

There is something i don't get in this part of a course :

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Skt.png)

I understand the part about how *the highest number of 8 digits in binary is also the highest number of two digits in hexadecimal* ( 255 )

But can you explain : "concatenate bytes in either base and get the same result"

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What they are saying is that, assumw you have two adjacent bytes in memory (X and Y),and you have their values in hexadecimal or binary strings. The value of the two-byte integer consisting of X and Y in hex is the same as the hex string representing X concatenated with the string representing Y.

Thus, if X = AB and Y = CD then (X,Y) =ABCD.

This also works in binary but it does not work in decimal.

Comment: Thanks! Guess i was tired, it was under my nose. So hexa is more efficient to represent bytes as you concat smaller strings to get the value you store ( ex the value 43981 in a 2 Bytes int, can be represented as 0xAB and 0xCD )